# Apparently you can't download from GitHub from within a GitHub action

Tags: github-actions, rakudo-star

I have tried to use git clone as well as download a zip file from inside a GitHub action, and bot silently fail with an exit code 1. Is that a known bug or a feature?
It might happen only if we're using the Windows-latest environment, for instance [here](https://github.com/JJ/raku-advent-calendar-article-2019/commit/2bb8e9f5fa93cc649e31b4094446eb5fe51d8492/checks?check_suite_id=343141136) (which is simply trying to download a raw file from a repository)

This is the debug output:

```
[2019-12-05 07:18:07Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'af8d91f7-ccf0-5f84-75dc-a9a0616a8cbb', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:18:07Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to upload 1 log files or attachments, success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:18:08Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'af8d91f7-ccf0-5f84-75dc-a9a0616a8cbb', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:18:09Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'af8d91f7-ccf0-5f84-75dc-a9a0616a8cbb', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:18:09Z INFO AddMaskCommandExtension] Add new secret mask with length of 80
[2019-12-05 07:18:09Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'af8d91f7-ccf0-5f84-75dc-a9a0616a8cbb', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:18:12Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 2 batches web console lines for record 'af8d91f7-ccf0-5f84-75dc-a9a0616a8cbb', success rate: 2/2.
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'af8d91f7-ccf0-5f84-75dc-a9a0616a8cbb', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Finished process 524 with exit code 0, and elapsed time 00:00:06.0176319.
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO StepsRunner] Step result: 
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO StepsRunner] No need for updating job result with current step result 'Succeeded'.
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO StepsRunner] Current state: job state = ''
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO StepsRunner] Processing step: DisplayName='Install and update'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ExpressionManager] Parsing expression: <success()>
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ExpressionManager] Evaluating: success()
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ExpressionManager] Result: true
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO StepsRunner] Starting the step.
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': 'c:\runners\2.162.0\bin'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Root': 'c:\runners\2.162.0'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Work': 'd:\a'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO StepsRunner] Which: 'chcp'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO StepsRunner] Location: 'C:\windows\system32\chcp.COM'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Starting process:
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   File name: 'C:\windows\system32\chcp.COM'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Arguments: '65001'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Working directory: 'd:\a'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Require exit code zero: 'False'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Encoding web name:  ; code page: ''
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Redirected STDIN: 'False'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Persist current code page: 'True'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   High priority process: 'False'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Process started with process id 5520, waiting for process exit.
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Finished process 5520 with exit code 0, and elapsed time 00:00:00.0065777.
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO StepsRunner] Successfully returned to code page 65001 (UTF8)
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': 'c:\runners\2.162.0\bin'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Root': 'c:\runners\2.162.0'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Work': 'd:\a'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Temp': 'd:\a\_temp'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionRunner] Write event payload to d:\a\_temp\_github_workflow\event.json
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ExtensionManager] Getting extensions for interface: 'GitHub.Runner.Worker.IActionCommandExtension'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command internal-set-repo-path
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command set-env
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command set-output
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command save-state
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command add-path
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command add-mask
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command add-matcher
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command remove-matcher
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command warning
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command error
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command debug
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command group
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command endgroup
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ActionCommandManager] Register action command extension for command echo
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ScriptHandler] Which: 'pwsh'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ScriptHandler] Location: 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.EXE'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': 'c:\runners\2.162.0\bin'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Root': 'c:\runners\2.162.0'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Work': 'd:\a'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Temp': 'd:\a\_temp'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ScriptHandler] Which: 'pwsh'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ScriptHandler] Location: 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.EXE'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Starting process:
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   File name: 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.EXE'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Arguments: '-command ". 'd:\a\_temp\9d413328-d3df-48bd-a2b7-39f86b853936.ps1'"'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Working directory: 'd:\a\raku-advent-calendar-article-2019\raku-advent-calendar-article-2019'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Require exit code zero: 'False'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Encoding web name:  ; code page: ''
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Redirected STDIN: 'False'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Persist current code page: 'True'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   High priority process: 'False'
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'af8d91f7-ccf0-5f84-75dc-a9a0616a8cbb', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:18:13Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Process started with process id 4848, waiting for process exit.
[2019-12-05 07:18:14Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to upload 1 log files or attachments, success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:18:28Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:19:08Z INFO JobServerQueue] Stop aggressive process web console line queue.
[2019-12-05 07:19:41Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:19:42Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:19:42Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:19:43Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:19:46Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:19:46Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:19:47Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:19:48Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:19:50Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:20:12Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:20:12Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:20:14Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:21:01Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:21:46Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:21:56Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines for record 'd9e82cb8-8576-553a-4379-ea55bebeec28', success rate: 1/1.
[2019-12-05 07:22:01Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Scan all processes to find relationship between all processes.
[2019-12-05 07:22:01Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Find all child processes of process '4848'.
[2019-12-05 07:22:01Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Need kill all child processes trees before kill process '4848'.
[2019-12-05 07:22:01Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Child process '6780' needs be killed first.
[2019-12-05 07:22:01Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Find all child processes of process '6780'.
[2019-12-05 07:22:01Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Need kill all child processes trees before kill process '6780'.
[2019-12-05 07:22:01Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Child process '6372' needs be killed first.
[2019-12-05 07:22:01Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Find all child processes of process '6372'.
[2019-12-05 07:22:01Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Kill process '6372'.
[2019-12-05 07:22:01Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Kill process '6780'.
[2019-12-05 07:22:01Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Kill process '4848'.
[2019-12-05 07:22:01Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Finished process 4848 with exit code 1, and elapsed time 00:03:47.8885524.
```

It does not really give much more information...

Comment: Can you turn on [debug logging](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/managing-a-workflow-run#enabling-debug-logging) to get more output? It is not clear why your script is failing

Comment: @smac89 testing, but the result is consistent and always the same. The problem with Windows might be that it's running on the bare container, unlike those that are using docker containers, and thus the access to GitHub might be limited; it has no trouble downloading from anywhere else.

Comment: The debug output tells petty much the same, but much more verbosely.

Comment: I see. Can you try the suggestion [here](https://github.com/ugexe/zef/issues/306#issuecomment-513487833)

Comment: @smac89 thanks, I appreciate that, but that's exactly what I was trying to do. Only I can't because it fails when I try to do anything with github. After failing to either git clone or download a zip file from a GitHub repository, I tried a checkout action and that worked, only to fail later when doing a zef update, which again tries to download something from GitHub